# Markers are not working in Google Maps V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

So this is How I'm Trying to place the marker on my map. The maps are being loaded but the markers aren't. 
The

```
var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(27.681874953576184, 85.32536029815674);

      myMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: myLatLng,
                  map: map,
                });
        myMarker.setMap(map);
```

Supposed to be working but it isn't. Could anyone help me to point my error out?

```js
 var myMarker;
    var myLatLng;
    var mapData = [];
    var markerArray = [];
    var map;
    var lcoationsArray = [];

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var formStr = "<input type='text' id='text4mrkr' class='textinput textInput form-control' /><input type='button' class='btn btn-success' value='Add Bus Stop' onclick='addPlace();' />"

    var loadMap = function() {
      var myPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(27.685280944522653, 85.31990468502045);
      var mapOptions = {
        center: myPosition,
        zoom: 10,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        clickable: true,
        scrollwheel: false,
        navigationControl: false,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        scaleControl: false,
        zoomControl: true
      };
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapcontainer"), mapOptions);

      google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
        this.setOptions({scrollwheel:true});
      });
      google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mouseover', function(event){
        self = this;
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
          self.setOptions({scrollwheel:true});
        }, 1000);
      });
      google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mouseout', function(event){
        this.setOptions({scrollwheel:false});
        clearTimeout(timer);
      });


    };
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', loadMap);

 
      var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(27.681874953576184, 85.32536029815674);

      myMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: myLatLng,
                  map: map,
                });
        myMarker.setMap(map);
```

```css
html, body, #mapcontainer {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
   <script src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12" id = "mapcontainer" style = "height:580px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating the marker outside of the `loadMap` function, so it is being created **before** the map is created (which is created when the `onload` event fires).  Move the marker creation inside the `loadMap` function.

```js
var myMarker;
var myLatLng;
var mapData = [];
var markerArray = [];
var map;
var lcoationsArray = [];

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var formStr = "<input type='text' id='text4mrkr' class='textinput textInput form-control' /><input type='button' class='btn btn-success' value='Add Bus Stop' onclick='addPlace();' />"

var loadMap = function() {
  var myPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(27.685280944522653, 85.31990468502045);
  var mapOptions = {
    center: myPosition,
    zoom: 10,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    clickable: true,
    scrollwheel: false,
    navigationControl: false,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    scaleControl: false,
    zoomControl: true
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapcontainer"), mapOptions);

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    this.setOptions({
      scrollwheel: true
    });
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mouseover', function(event) {
    self = this;
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      self.setOptions({
        scrollwheel: true
      });
    }, 1000);
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mouseout', function(event) {
    this.setOptions({
      scrollwheel: false
    });
    clearTimeout(timer);
  });

  var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(27.681874953576184, 85.32536029815674);

  myMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
  });
  myMarker.setMap(map);
};
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', loadMap);


var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(27.681874953576184, 85.32536029815674);

myMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatLng,
  map: map,
});
myMarker.setMap(map);
```

```css
html,
body,
#mapcontainer {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12" id="mapcontainer" style="height:580px;"></div>
```